# alternating and shifting sections of an array

Tags: arrays, octave

I have a n x m array **(could be any size array but it will not be a 1 x m)** and I want to rotate / shift each square loop individually no matter the array size.

How can I alternate the rotation / shift each square loop no matter the size of the array.

> Please note: I'm not trying to calculate the values in the array but shift the values.

My thought process was to get the values of each "square loop" and place them into one row and do a circshift then place them back into another array.

I ran into problems trying to get the values back into the original n x m array size and I wasn't sure how I could loop through the process for different n x m arrays.

The **pink** highlighted section, **left of the arrows** is the starting position of the array and it's "loops" and the **green** highlighted section, **right of the arrows** is the type of rotation / shift of the values that I'm trying to create.  **The array could have more than 3 "loops" this is just an example.**

**Code below:**

```
I=[1:5;6:10;11:15;16:20;21:25;26:30]

[rw,col] = size(I);

outer_1=[I(1,:),I(2:end-1,end).',I(end,end:-1:1),I(end-1:-1:2,1).'] %get values in one row (so I can shift values)
outer_1_shift=circshift(outer_1,[0 1]) %shift values 
new_array=zeros(rw,col);
```

[image: Shift Process]

Ps: I'm using Octave 4.2.2 Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Generate the index vector for your "look" first. You can calculate it from n,m and the "loop number". Then usw this index to extract the values, circshift, then store the shifted vector back using the same index. Or circshift the index (which would give the same result)

Comment: The same question in [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112015)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: The circshift function was changed for Octave 5.0, the last edit made it compatible with previous versions

```
1;

function r = rndtrip (n, m, v)
  rv = @(x) x - 2 * (v - 1);
  r = [v * ones(1,rv(m)-1) v:n-v+1 (n-v+1)*ones(1,rv(m)-2)];
  if (rv(m) > 1)
    r = [r n-v+1:-1:v+1];
  endif
endfunction

function idx = ring (n, m , v)

  if (2*(v-1) > min (n, m))
    r = [];
  else
    r = rndtrip (n, m, v);
    c = circshift (rndtrip (m, n, v)(:), - n + 2 * v - 1).';
    idx = sub2ind ([n m], r, c);
  endif

endfunction

# your I
I = reshape (1:30, 5, 6).';

# positive is clockwise, negative ccw
r = [1 -1 1];

for k = 1:numel(r)

  idx = ring (rows(I), columns(I), k);
  I(idx) = I(circshift(idx(:), r(k)));

endfor

I
```

gives

```
I =

    6    1    2    3    4
   11    8    9   14    5
   16    7   18   19   10
   21   12   13   24   15
   26   17   22   23   20
   27   28   29   30   25
```

[run it on tio](https://tio.run/##bVHLbsIwELznK0bqoTYkVZ2qPQQV9ZpvQByoMWBBbGQnhn493TgPHm0uXs@Md3cmVtaroC4X0CdmSdKem8bIWlsDh084s66dPoKZFFWKwKMEcIHIL3bmOCNDjglYoELw2SAgfhEIt0Z5JlIXWMUzwREKk4WpoI7twSd3fM6XQwO9AYsg5tS2B/u@DvFxkYmCjvGJMmu9SfpqsPFgSq/PrS1ttp0nRFM3M/MJC@2ec1TadBr@MP468ODVHfUnrtlIS6KldtLv9KYma4OSZKZVsoKnlKDBNMbZpfnyfG3Qbe6b71ybNdjCoFqmcCkkvw/g/wSe8GMbhzJeynZX5XerowITxdtrivcUH3Ferz5ar2sdFLSHPFi5P2mvaFe1XUVYylMyJiKQCbQ/ogvbOuwJFoVpKnVg7hrwTfrOnjwrybS0h6YyXb0fvZSMxJzUJRtja6GYk2N7zvnsatW6ri4vl18)

Comment: Thanks! I just tested your code online at `https://octave-online.net/` and the variable / array `I` doesn't seem to match

Comment: I tired my local Octave 4.2.2, then I tried `try it online` version which is 4.2.2 and Octave online which is 4.2.1. I think it has to with url shortening why the link didn't work.  I added the full URL link to your answer.  It was to long to post in the comments.

Comment: It was this http://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/rev/8be616a0b9aa cset which changed circshift

Comment: I've updated the code here: https://github.com/octave-de/macgyver_utils/blob/master/ring.m

Answer (score 1):

So, I had the same idea as in [Andy's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573666/alternating-and-shifting-sections-of-an-array#comment99725674_56573666). Nevertheless, since I was already preparing some code, here is my suggestion:

```matlab
% Input.
I = reshape(1:30, 5, 6).'
[m, n] = size(I);

% Determine number of loops.
nLoops = min(ceil([m, n] / 2));

% Iterate loops.
for iLoop = 1:nLoops

  % Determine number of repetitions per row / column.
  row = n - 2 * (iLoop - 1);
  col = m - 2 * (iLoop - 1);

  % Initialize indices.
  idx = [];

  % Add top row indices.
  idx = [idx, [repelem(iLoop, row).']; iLoop:(n-(iLoop-1))];

  % Add right column indices.
  idx = [idx, [[iLoop+1:(m-(iLoop-1))]; repelem(n-(iLoop-1), col-1).']];

  if (iLoop != m-(iLoop-1))

    % Add bottom row indices.
    idx = [idx, [repelem(m-(iLoop-1), row-1).'; (n-(iLoop-1)-1:-1:iLoop)]]

  end

  if (iLoop != n-(iLoop-1))

    % Add left column indices.
    idx = [idx, [[(m-(iLoop-1))-1:-1:iLoop+1]; repelem(iLoop, col-2).']]

  end

  % Convert subscript indices to linear indices.
  idx = sub2ind(size(I), idx(1, :), idx(2, :));

  % Determine direction for circular shift operation.
  if (mod(iLoop, 2) == 1)
    direction = [0 1];
  else
    direction = [0 -1];
  end

  % Replace values in I.
  I(idx) = circshift(I(idx), direction);

end

% Output.
I
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't think of a smarter way to generate the indices, since you need to maintain the right order and avoid double indices. As you can see, I obtain subscript indices with respect to `I`, since this can be done quite easy using the matrix dimensions and number of loops. Nevertheless, for the `circshift` operation and later replacing of the values in `I`, linear indices are more handy, so that's why the [`sub2ind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) operation.

Input and output look like this:

```matlab
I =
    1    2    3    4    5
    6    7    8    9   10
   11   12   13   14   15
   16   17   18   19   20
   21   22   23   24   25
   26   27   28   29   30

I =
    6    1    2    3    4
   11    8    9   14    5
   16    7   18   19   10
   21   12   13   24   15
   26   17   22   23   20
   27   28   29   30   25
```

I was right, that the "shift direction" changes with every loop?

Hope that helps!

Caution: I haven't tested for generality, yet. So, please report any errors you might come across.

Comment: Thanks but it seems to not run in Octave 4.2.1 or 4.2.2 I get an error `error: 'repelem' undefined near line 12 column 15` I tried testing on [Octave run online](http://octave-online.net) and
try it online [HansHirse Code tested and run online](http://shorturl.at/owAN5)

Comment: we just added `repelem` recently and I think it only finally made it into Octave v5.0.  you can find the final version attached the missing function bug report:  https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?45497  I don't think there was anything in there that wouldn't be 4.2 compatible. Octave also has `repelems` with a different syntax that may do what you want.