# error: sub2ind: all subscripts must be of the same size using Octave 4.2.2

Tags: arrays, octave

I'm getting an **error: sub2ind: all subscripts must be of the same size.**  The line that seems to be the issue is `idx = sub2ind ([n m], r, c)`

If I try and make the array certain sizes I get that error (see some of the values below that cause the issue)

```
%values that cause the error
array_rows=3;  %3,3,7,7
array_cols=6;  %6,5,3,5
```

How can I get it to work with these values and others that cause this error (I'm sure there are more values that cause this error)?

**The Original question:** was answered and solved by [Andy here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573666/alternating-and-shifting-sections-of-an-array/56580908#56580908)

See code below:

```
    function r = rndtrip (n, m, v)
      rv = @(x) x - 2 * (v - 1);
      r = [v * ones(1,rv(m)-1) v:n-v+1 (n-v+1)*ones(1,rv(m)-2)];
      if (rv(m) > 1)
        r = [r n-v+1:-1:v+1];
      endif
    endfunction

    function idx = ring (n, m , v)

      if (2*(v-1) > min (n, m))
        r = [];
      else
        r = rndtrip (n, m, v);
        c = circshift (rndtrip (m, n, v)(:), - n + 2 * v - 1).';
        idx = sub2ind ([n m], r, c)

      endif

    endfunction

    # your array
    array_rows=3;  %3,3,7,7
    array_cols=6;  %6,5,3,5

    I_orig = reshape (1:array_rows*array_cols, array_cols, array_rows).' %reshape array %I_orig = reshape (1:30, 5, 6).' 
    [rw_orig col_orig]=size(I_orig);

    I_new=I_orig; %where the new rotated values will be stored

    min_rows_cols=min(rw_orig,col_orig); %get min number of row - columns used to calc number of rings

    r=(-1).^(1:ceil(min_rows_cols/2)) %  (toggles beween -1 1)
    %r = [1 -1] %used to have ring rotate CCW or CW can be done manually

    for k = 1:numel(r)
      idx = ring (rows(I_new), columns(I_new), k);
      I_new(idx) = I_new(circshift(idx(:), r(k)));
    endfor

    I_new





I_orig =

        1    2    3    4    5    6
        7    8    9   10   11   12
       13   14   15   16   17   18

r =

      -1   1
idx =

        1    4    7   10   13   16   17   18   15   12    9    6    3    2
error: sub2ind: all subscripts must be of the same size
error: called from ring at line 16 column 9
```

[Values that Work with the Code run on TIO](https://tio.run/##bVPbbuIwEH3PVxxpFa1NTXcDgkpBVCv1ab9gHyq2CokBi8Su7Fxgf54d20BB7YvjuZ05Mz4xZVv08nTadLpsldGwWMLqqrXqHUwLNAI9TwDbU@AXO3AcMMYEI7CeLhlf@CDFXnvyGS0dy4TtWcPHGUef63H/kBGS//DRXXzCV75YbcCCA88ER44znkUoysdZTp@QKnWlNgmdF7pJciWuqoOnrvQ28kYgfsafjFjv@TyjUTrG@U2rCF47eXV9WsEihEoKlcqWbqc2LdG@ZFGK9lks54K2ovEQVhQ39Pg9FkeGrltPlK7AXjWalYAVKAPPONz9dN9wNJ1FYW1xTML5Zs3glrMFkE7FVDyJp7O/NLVbzr1/LmYUmSXJ7zdj1dZPI92ueJdgWf4BMvqoE/h89ylEHemlOLiRfgU6/SkwE5j7/OTVDjGF0MJltXTqn2SxkBZJvLQcltFeIB120kq0Owlyw5q2aGWFvqg76TCousZawrXGyipJ6P0CtTgvWezcTlzacYLcyja8tO6atbQwG4Id6DEop2u0Q@eoQ2tQFnV5m0TqcUlil4zE8viXJiulqtldzx8TzpHCWNykTTnAWrPd1kR5LQcpNcaZl3MaBJaRtUJ6abujfy5KNU6Ll5c/HpHOstB@3Ir@FDRFV9T1kUROsT3hZDlxlTWzXru3gvfsWFgr6e885NXeB/EGi1ERp6poXJXs3UG6lu05p3QvQmPPL3U6/Qc)

[Values that don't work with the Code run on TIO](https://tio.run/##bVPbbuIwEH3PVxxpFa1NTXcDgkpBVCv1ab9gHyq2CokBi8Su7Fxgf54d20BB7YvjuZ05Mz4xZVv08nTadLpsldGwWMLqqrXqHUwLNAI9TwDbU@AXO3AcMMYEI7CeLhlf@CDFXnvyGS0dy4TtWcPHGUef63H/kBGS//DRXXzCV75YbcCCA88ER44znkUoysdZTp@QKnWlNgmdF7pJciWuqoOnrvQ28kYgfsafjFjv@TyjUTrG@U2rCF47eXV9WsEihEoKlcqWbqc2LdG@ZFGK9lks54K2ovEQVhQ39Pg9FkeGrltPlK7AXjWalYAVKAPPONz9dN9wNJ1FYW1xTML5Zs3gltMFkE7FVDyJp7O/NLVbzr1/LmYUmSXJ7zdj1dZPI92ueJdgWf4BMvqoE/h89ylEHemlOLiRfgU6/SkwE5j7/OTVDjGF0MJltXTqn2SxkBZJvLQcltFeIB120kq0Owlyw5q2aGWFvqg76TCousZawrXGyipJ6P0CtTgvWezcTlzacYLcyja8tO6atbQwG4Id6DEop2u0Q@eoQ2tQFnV5m0TqcUlil4zE8viXJiulqtldzx8TzpHCWNykTTnAWrPd1kR5LQcpNcaZl3MaBJaRtUJ6abujfy5KNU6Ll5c/HpHOstB@3Ir@FDRFV9T1kUROsT3hZDlxlTWzXru3gvfsWFgr6e885NXeB/EGi1ERp6poXJXs3UG6lu05p3QvQmPPL3U6/Qc)

**Ps: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 Octave 4.2.2**

Comment: I haven't checked my code for matrices, which more columns than rows. you have to fix rndtrip for this or transpose them, rotate in opposite and transpose back for a quick workaround

Comment: @Andy I tried transposing rndtrip `.'` and I'm still getting the error any other ideas?

Comment: I've updated the code here: https://github.com/octave-de/macgyver_utils/blob/master/ring.m